# How to sleep with mulesoft flow designer

Tags: mulesoft

I want to implement few second sleep (delay) to express delaying processing on mulesoft flow designer.
If the above doesn't work, can mulesoft anypoint platform do it?

client → (request) → server(mulesoft)
..few second sleep..
client ← (response) ← server(mulesoft)

Comment: What exactly is the need or requirement for trying to sleep the flow? It is  a bad practice and can cause issues.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
Because it's a mock of time-consuming processing.

Comment: Good personal hygiene, best behaviour, ask them nicely, be respectful and hope for consent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't recommend to use any kind of sleep in variants Mule applications unless you have very clear the impact it may have and how it affects resource usage. I have written a blog article explaining the problems it can cause: https://medium.com/@adobni/sleep-will-make-your-mule-runtime-slow-b7b80303c78

**WARNING**: this should be done **only for very simple tests and never ever be used in a production application, nor for benchmarks and load tests**. Failing to follow this warning can cause **outages** or the case of tests it can cause unrealistic results.

You can use the wait() function in a Transform script to cause an artificial delay.

Note that the bigger the delay is, the easiest to run out of resources to process requests.

Comment: I really like such kind of explanations from you!! it clears most of the concepts and facts

Answer (score 2):

Here is a link to a lib that allows exactly that in Flow Designer.
https://github.com/rbutenuth/rate-limiter

Answer (score 0):

Update wait time Based on your Requirement

```
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::Runtime
output application/json
---
{ "user" : 1 } wait 2000
```